# cover cut edge of kitchen worktop

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters

Just fitted a kitchen from ikea... all but the worktops.

Our kitchen is a corner kitchen.

The worktops we have been provided are a stock length and need to be cut down in length to fit.

After I have cut the worktop, at the section where one work top meets the other, what am i meant to use to cover the cut edge and seal from water ingress? Wonderfully Ikea don't supply anything for this.

Comment: What kind of counters are these? Formica? Laminate?

Comment: Laminate I think, with a chipboard core.

Comment: They should make an 'iron on' edge that has a heat activated glue to cover the ends. This might be an optional purchase.

Comment: Google "worktop joining strip" or "worktop jointing strip". (I'm assuming you're not in North America, where those things are hard to find.) Load up the cut edge with silicone sealant for waterproofness and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formica is the material that is usually glued to the countertop.
Normally you clean the top with acetone and put  a “Seamfil” compound with a putty knife.
They have different brands other than Seamfil but pick the brand that most closely matches your color.
There will be a stripe as it never matches exactly but it will seal and keep the material from “puckering” or filling up with Gunk.